# Illustration of Lagrange multipliers

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw with pgfplots and/or tikz an illustration of Lagrange multipliers.

For reminder, Lagrange multipliers are used to optimize thing like this:

min_x f(x) such that g(x)=0

Basically, I need to be able to draw a 3D surface that corresponds to f(x), which is easy.

But I also need to draw a curve on that surface that cuts it at the intersection of f(x) and g(x). And I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: where is f and g?

Comment: It could be any f or g. I'm looking for a general way to do this. But in my example, f(x,y)=20*x*exp(-x^2-y^2) and g(x,y)=(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2.

Comment: The most general way is to generate a table of solutions outside Tikz and plot that (smooth).

Comment: Comment: Envoke `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` in the preamble.

Comment: It would be best to convert the solution in your edit into an answer. (It is perfectly OK to answer you own question and makes things a whole lot clearer for other users with the same question.)

Comment: @davcha can you write a self-answer for this one as cfr suggested?

Comment: I'll do this later. Not on m'y computer right now

Answer (score 4):

Aside from solving the constraints symbolically, you could solve them numerically. To this end, you can use any contouring algorithm and compute level Z = 0:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={f(\x,\y)=20*\x*exp(-\x^2-\y^2);},
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
        width=300pt,
        height=300pt,
        domain=-2:2,
        view={-60}{30},
    ]
        \addplot3 [surf, opacity=.3, samples=50] {f(x,y)};

        % needed just once... it has no output    
        \addplot3 [samples=50,mark=none, contour gnuplot={labels=false,levels={5},handler/.style={only marks}}] {(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2};

        \addplot3[black] table[x index=0, y index=1, z expr={f(x,y)}] {P_contourtmp0.table};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since the solutions of 0 = g(x,y) = (x+1)^2+(y-1)^2 are (-1, 1), I chose g(x,y) = 5 as constraints.

This needs to be compiled with `-shell-escape` due to the use of `gnuplot`. Note that the `gnuplot` output is actually recomputed everytime the figure is typeset -- unnecessarily. You can uncomment the `gnuplot` instruction after the first run. The `handler/.style={only marks}` instructs the `contour` handler to show just the configured `mark` (which is none per default here).

The key idea is that the plot instruction to overlay the result into the surface is to use `z expr={f(x,y)}`. In this context, "`x`" and "`y`" are the coordinates read from the input file and `f` is the common declaration.

You can safely use `compat=1.11` instead of `1.12` here (1.12 just needs half of the time when compiled with `lualatex`).

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution.
It consist in converting the solutions g(x)=0 to polar coordinates and plotting it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[   width=300pt,
                    height=300pt,
                    axis background/.style={fill=white},
                    xticklabels=\empty,
                    yticklabels=\empty,
                    zticklabels=\empty,
                    xtick scale label code/.code={},
                    ytick scale label code/.code={},
                    ztick scale label code/.code={},
                    clip marker paths=true,
                    domain=-2:2,
                    view={-60}{30}
                ]
        \addplot3 [surf, opacity=.3, samples=50] {20*(x)*exp(-x^2-y^2)};
        \addplot3 [domain=0:2*pi, samples y=0, samples=300] ({
                (cos(deg(4*x))*.5+.75)*cos(deg(x))
            },{
                (cos(deg(4*x))*.5+.75)*sin(deg(x))
            },{
                20*(((cos(deg(4*x))*.5+.75)*cos(deg(x))))*exp(-((cos(deg(4*x))*.5+.75)*cos(deg(x)))^2-((cos(deg(4*x))*.5+.75)*sin(deg(x)))^2)
            });
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]